# Unable to change background in mate desktop

Tags: debian, mate-desktop, settings, dconf

I'm running Debian Stretch with MATE desktop 1.16.1. Since I have update the package `mate-settings-daemon` I can't change my background, it shows the wallpaper used for the login screen. I've tried to change it in the usual way through Control Center -> Appearance -> Background but when I select a new wallpaper nothing happens. I've also tried to change some configurations with `dconf editor` but again with no success. 
Here are the packages about MATE desktop that I have in my system:

```
ii  atril                                 1.16.1-2                          amd64        MATE document viewer
ii  atril-common                          1.16.1-2                          all          MATE document viewer (common files)
ii  caja                                  1.16.2-2                          amd64        file manager for the MATE desktop
ii  caja-common                           1.16.2-2                          all          file manager for the MATE desktop (common files)
ii  compiz-mate                           1:0.9.13.0+16.10.20160818.2-5     amd64        OpenGL window and compositing manager - MATE integration
ii  debian-mate-default-settings          1.16.1-1                          all          Default settings for MATE on Debian
ii  engrampa                              1.16.0-2                          amd64        archive manager for MATE
ii  engrampa-common                       1.16.0-2                          all          archive manager for MATE (common files)
ii  eom                                   1.16.0-2                          amd64        Eye of MATE graphics viewer program
ii  eom-common                            1.16.0-2                          all          Eye of MATE graphics viewer program (common files)
ii  gir1.2-mate-panel                     1.16.2-1                          amd64        GObject introspection data for MATE panel
ii  libamd2:amd64                         1:4.5.4-1                         amd64        approximate minimum degree ordering library for sparse matrices
ii  libatrildocument3                     1.16.1-2                          amd64        MATE document rendering library
ii  libatrilview3                         1.16.1-2                          amd64        MATE document viewing library
ii  libcamd2:amd64                        1:4.5.4-1                         amd64        symmetric approximate minimum degree library for sparse matrices
ii  libccolamd2:amd64                     1:4.5.4-1                         amd64        constrained column approximate library for sparse matrices
ii  libcolamd2:amd64                      1:4.5.4-1                         amd64        column approximate minimum degree ordering library for sparse matrices
ii  libmate-desktop-2-17:amd64            1.16.1-1                          amd64        Library with common API for various MATE modules (library)
ii  libmate-menu2:amd64                   1.16.0-2                          amd64        implementation of the freedesktop menu specification for MATE (library)
ii  libmate-panel-applet-4-1              1.16.2-1                          amd64        library for MATE Panel applets
ii  libmate-sensors-applet-plugin0        1.16.1-1                          amd64        Library for plugins for the mate-sensors-applet package
ii  libmate-slab0:amd64                   1.16.1-1                          amd64        beautification app library
ii  libmate-window-settings1:amd64        1.16.1-1                          amd64        utilities to configure the MATE desktop (window settings library)
ii  libmatedict6                          1.16.0-1                          amd64        MATE desktop utilities (matedict library)
ii  libmatekbd-common                     1.16.0-2                          all          MATE library to manage keyboard configuration (common files)
ii  libmatekbd4:amd64                     1.16.0-2                          amd64        MATE library to manage keyboard configuration
ii  libmatemixer-common                   1.16.0-2                          all          Mixer library for MATE Desktop (common files)
ii  libmatemixer0:amd64                   1.16.0-2                          amd64        Mixer library for MATE Desktop
ii  libmateweather-common                 1.16.1-2                          all          MateWeather shared library (common files)
ii  libmateweather1:amd64                 1.16.1-2                          amd64        MateWeather shared library
ii  marco                                 1.16.0-1                          amd64        lightweight GTK+ window manager for MATE
ii  marco-common                          1.16.0-1                          all          lightweight GTK+ window manager for MATE (common files)
ii  mate-applet-brisk-menu                0.3.5-0ubuntu1                    amd64        Solus Project's Brisk Menu MATE Panel Applet
ii  mate-applet-topmenu                   0.3-1                             amd64        Topmenu applet for the MATE panel
ii  mate-applets                          1.16.0-1                          amd64        Various applets for the MATE panel
ii  mate-applets-common                   1.16.0-1                          all          Various applets for the MATE panel (common files)
ii  mate-backgrounds                      1.16.0-1                          all          Set of backgrounds packaged with the MATE Desktop Environment
ii  mate-control-center                   1.16.1-1                          amd64        utilities to configure the MATE desktop
ii  mate-control-center-common            1.16.1-1                          all          utilities to configure the MATE desktop (common files)
ii  mate-desktop                          1.16.1-1                          amd64        Library with common API for various MATE modules
ii  mate-desktop-common                   1.16.1-1                          all          Library with common API for various MATE modules (common files)
ii  mate-desktop-environment              1.16.0+1                          all          MATE Desktop Environment (metapackage)
ii  mate-desktop-environment-core         1.16.0+1                          all          MATE Desktop Environment (essential components, metapackage)
ii  mate-desktop-environment-extras       1.16.0+1                          all          MATE Desktop Environment (extra components, metapackage)
ii  mate-icon-theme                       1.16.2-1                          all          MATE Desktop icon theme
ii  mate-icon-theme-faenza                1.16.0+dfsg1-2                    all          MATE Faenza Desktop icon theme
ii  mate-indicator-applet                 1.16.0-1                          amd64        MATE panel indicator applet
ii  mate-indicator-applet-common          1.16.0-1                          all          MATE panel indicator applet (common files)
ii  mate-media                            1.16.0-1                          amd64        MATE media utilities
ii  mate-media-common                     1.16.0-1                          all          MATE media utilities (common files)
ii  mate-menu                             16.10.1-2                         all          Advanced MATE menu
ii  mate-menus                            1.16.0-2                          amd64        implementation of the freedesktop menu specification for MATE
ii  mate-notification-daemon              1.16.1-1                          amd64        daemon to display passive popup notifications
ii  mate-notification-daemon-common       1.16.1-1                          all          daemon to display passive popup notifications (common files)
ii  mate-panel                            1.16.2-1                          amd64        launcher and docking facility for MATE
ii  mate-panel-common                     1.16.2-1                          all          launcher and docking facility for MATE (common files)
ii  mate-polkit:amd64                     1.16.0-2                          amd64        MATE authentication agent for PolicyKit-1
ii  mate-polkit-common                    1.16.0-2                          amd64        MATE authentication agent for PolicyKit-1 (common files)
ii  mate-power-manager                    1.16.2-1                          amd64        power management tool for the MATE desktop
ii  mate-power-manager-common             1.16.2-1                          all          power management tool for the MATE desktop (common files)
ii  mate-screensaver                      1.16.1-1                          amd64        MATE screen saver and locker
ii  mate-screensaver-common               1.16.1-1                          all          MATE screen saver and locker (common files)
ii  mate-sensors-applet                   1.16.1-1                          amd64        Display readings from hardware sensors in your MATE panel
ii  mate-sensors-applet-common            1.16.1-1                          all          Display readings from hardware sensors in your MATE panel (common files)
ii  mate-session-manager                  1.16.1-1                          amd64        Session manager of the MATE desktop environment
ii  mate-settings-daemon                  1.16.2-1                          amd64        daemon handling the MATE session settings
ii  mate-settings-daemon-common           1.16.2-1                          all          daemon handling the MATE session settings (common files)
ii  mate-system-monitor                   1.16.0-2                          amd64        Process viewer and system resource monitor for MATE
ii  mate-system-monitor-common            1.16.0-2                          all          Process viewer and system resource monitor for MATE (common files)
ii  mate-terminal                         1.16.2-1                          amd64        MATE terminal emulator application
ii  mate-terminal-common                  1.16.2-1                          all          MATE terminal emulator application (common files)
ii  mate-themes                           3.22.6-1                          all          Official themes for the MATE desktop
ii  mate-tweak                            16.10.5-1                         all          MATE desktop tweak tool
ii  mate-user-guide                       1.16.0-1                          all          User documentation for MATE Desktop Environment
ii  mate-utils                            1.16.0-1                          amd64        MATE desktop utilities
ii  mate-utils-common                     1.16.0-1                          all          MATE desktop utilities (common files)
ii  mozo                                  1.16.0-1                          all          easy MATE menu editing tool
ii  pluma                                 1.16.1-1                          amd64        official text editor of the MATE desktop environment
ii  pluma-common                          1.16.1-1                          all          official text editor of the MATE desktop environment (common files)
ii  python-mate-menu                      1.16.0-2                          amd64        implementation of the freedesktop menu specification for MATE (Python bindings)
ii  task-mate-desktop                     3.39                              all          MATE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same problem.

A quick workaround could be to use feh:

```
feh --bg-scale <imagefile.jpg>
```

Comment: @Checkinator It has already been reported: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=862355

Answer (score 3):

Another solution which doesn't need `feh` is the following.

It seems that the desktop wallpaper is stuck with the login background. So, you can change the login background and the only thing you need after that is logging out and in again (not restarting).

Changing the login background is done via [update-alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) (if anyone knows a better way, please tell me). As root user you have to issue two commands from the command line:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/share/images/desktop-base/login-background.svg desktop-login-background /absolute/path/of/your/image 50
update-alternatives --set desktop-login-background /absolute/path/of/your/image
```

Then log out and log back in and the wallpaper will be the one you selected. This is what worked for me at least, when I wasn't aware of that question; I wish I were. Hopefully the bug will be fixed, so that's for the impatient I guess.

---

**Bug fixed**: After the last update, the problem is fixed, so you can now change the background from the relevant menu and it should work as expected (worked for me at least).

Comment: Yes that works. You could also change the login background, theme and other options via GUI with `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings`! But maybe the best thing to do is to add the `feh` command at the startup application in the control center. This way it's possible to have two different backgrounds in login and desktop

Comment: `gsettings set org.mate.background picture-filename picture.jpg` works fine for me.